# How to drag images and disable swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, draggable, swipe

In PhoneGap application, I used `jquery.touchSwipe.js` to make transition between pages on swipe.

The problem is that I used also jquery.ui.touch-punch.js to drag some images in some pages and I don't know how to disable swipe in these images so that I can drag image and I don't leave the page.

**Edit**

```js
$("#imgleft11").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.top > 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        }
        var maxtop = ui.helper.parent().height() - ui.helper.height();
        if ( ui.position.top < maxtop) {
            ui.position.top = maxtop;
        }
        if ( ui.position.left > 0) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        }
        var maxleft = ui.helper.parent().width() - ui.helper.width();
        if ( ui.position.left < maxleft) {
            ui.position.left = maxleft;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post a sample of code are you used , on a standard way you must just use touch-punch to just drag able some images .

Comment: $("#imgleft11").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.top > 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        }
        var maxtop = ui.helper.parent().height() - ui.helper.height();
        if ( ui.position.top < maxtop) {
            ui.position.top = maxtop;
        }
        if ( ui.position.left > 0) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        }
        var maxleft = ui.helper.parent().width() - ui.helper.width();
        if ( ui.position.left < maxleft) {
            ui.position.left = maxleft;
        }
    }
});

Comment: Edit your post and paste the code there.